# Is it possible to reference the Azure SDK 1.1 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.* assemblies from a .NET 4.0 Client Profile project?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, azure

I have a WPF application targetting the *.NET 4.0 Client Profile* which needs to use the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.*` assemblies provided in the *Windows Azure SDK 1.1*.

The problem is that these assemblies have a runtime version of `v2.0.50727`. I am able to add references to them from my WPF project but they're not recognised.

I've read about the side by side execution capabilities of .NET 4.0 but does this require both the .NET 2.0 and the .NET 4.0 frameworks to be installed?

Is there anything from Microsoft on when a new SDK might be available that contains assemblies targeting .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 1.2 (June 2010)** have been released and bring full .NET 4.0 support:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2274a0a8-5d37-4eac-b50a-e197dc340f6f&displaylang=en

I'm assuming this now solves the problem I posted above but I've not tested it as I no longer need to reference these binaries from my client application.